# "Endpoint not found" Exception from One Machine but not from Other

Tags: wcf

I'm successfully running a WCF client program from my machine, but when I try running it from a different machine with the same configuration, I encounter the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no
endpoint listening at...
```

What can be the explanation for this? Is it possible that I made some configuration change to my machine that I'm not remembering now?

Comment: can you post the config file for the connecting client? I am suspecting that your client config file contains localhost :)

Comment: I'm not using a config file. Due to the complexity of the connection, all configuration is set programmatically, but "localhost" is not used anywhere.

Comment: how are you setting the url of the client? if you are doing programmatically, i would recommend you put a breakpoint at service call and try the address url from a browser

Comment: Is your "working" client and host on the same machine, and then you try from a different machine and it fails?  If so, firewall settings is something to look at.  If the working client is another machine, and so is the non-working one, then I dunno.

Comment: @Dhawalk: I set the url programmatically. The URL won't work from the browser because certificates and other credentials are involved as well.

Comment: @KevinAnderson: I'm consuming a third-party service using two different machines.

Comment: Please post your connection code then.  I've done WCF programmatically (I have more experience that way in fact) and if you have WSDL for your service, that'd be great too.  Or at the least, the ServiceContracts you're using on the client-side.  You're sure the code is the same on the two machines?

Comment: This is the wsdl URL: https://service100.emedny.org:9047/MHService?wsdl . I think the issue may be with the ISA server only allowing HTTPS connections on port 443 by default.